# What file is used to configure an entire web application and effects the entire web application?

Tags: java, servlets

What file is used to configure an entire web application and effects the entire web application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WEB-INF/web.xml` is used for java web applications.

Comment: Would that correctly be referred to as a "deployment descriptor"?